# Switching residences at night during Chanukah

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

The answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33593/defining-residence-for-purpose-of-candle-lighting) explain that if one is not eating at home during Chanukah, he nevertheless needs to light at his house, where he will be sleeping that night.

**What happens if someone switches his 'home' during one of the nights of Chanukah?**

As a concrete example, consider someone who owns two houses in two cities. He has been living in his house in City A for the past two months, and at sunset/nightfall is planning to leave his house later that night to move to his other house in City B for the next two months.

Does he light at sunset/nightfall in his first residence (where he has been sleeping on the previous nights)? Or in his new residence where he will only arrive later that night and where he will be sleeping from now on? (Or maybe he doesn't have an obligation to light at all?)

Does it make a difference how late at night he plans to move? Does it make a difference where he will be eating that night?

(Assume that this person forms his own household (or is traveling with his entire household) such that relying on others to light on his behalf in either location is not an option.)

Comment: ___Possibly___ a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50571/170

Comment: I don't have sources, but the basic concern of the [gemara](http://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_23.html) is that passers by would think that you were negligent to light Chanuka candles, as not all necessarily know that you've moved. So I think that in such case you would need to light at both places.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/12/guests-travelers-chanukah/) by R David Brofsky addresses (what seems to me to be) an equivalent question:

> When one goes away for Shabbat, for example, and returns home on Saturday night, where should he light Ḥanukka candles that night? Is his status determined by the place where he slept the night before or the place where he intends to sleep that night? Some suggest that if one can return home in time to light while there are still people outside, he should quickly return home after Shabbat and light there.[25] Others, however, maintain that one may light in his host’s house before returning home, particularly if he will be returning home late.[26]
>
> [25] *Ḥovat HaDar*, chap. 1, n. 65
>
> [26] *Yemei Hallel VeHoda’a*, p. 274, in the name of Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach.

Comment: I fail to see how does it answer your question.